Kotlin Thread in multi core
I'm new to Kotlin Trehad.
According to what I found, in Kotlin, threads and coroutines work with concurrency.
It seems that if I want to operate with parallelism, I can implement it using parallel of java stream or pmap.
if so,
Are both threads and coroutines concurrent in Kotlin?
So, when the CPU has multiple cores, does Kotlin's thread use only one core?

While Kotlin supports threads because of Java, Coroutines are the Kotlin correct way to do concurrent work.
Assuming we are running in the JVM - All other platforms have slight nuances to the following details
The "Coroutine Context" and the "Dispatcher" used to launch a given coroutine are what determines the Thread, and or the ThreadPool that the Coroutine is run on. The pool itself, can help manage the work across multiple Cores.
Since we're running in the JVM in this assumption, it will manage the threads and system integration of the threads. Synchronization and thread-safety are still managed by the JVM, as well as Memory allocation, and Garbage collection .
Overall, coroutines provide a simplified structure that abstracts away the complexity of managing threads, provides many different APIs to work efficiently, and maintains the power and efforts that the JVM does underlying to the system.
Threads offer a potential for more control, but you will have to build a lot more structure around them to get the simplicity that Coroutines offer out of the box.
Unless you need that extra control a non-coroutine tool provides, it will be less effort to work with Coroutines in Kotlin.

Thank you very much for your reply.
So, on a multi-core CPU, does the jvm run threads on multiple cores? In a single core CPU, threads are managed with concurrency, right?

Aren't there still situations where threads are necessary and coroutines can't help?  For example: blocking I/O.

@gidds Coroutines are implementations of Threads that abstract away a lot of the framework and setup required. I have used Coroutines to run USB buses with success in the past.

@박성현 The JVM will always manage the concurrency - Threads will be the underlying mechanism for this. Each Core on a CPU has a maximum number of threads it can have at a time.  In all situations, a single thread is tied to a single core. It is easier to think about a CPU having a maximum number of threads to work  with rather than being concerned about what Core a given thread is on. On the JVM there is no direct control to run code on a given Core, instead that is handled by the OS level scheduler.
